# Why are C# files (.cs) default Build Action "Content" instead of "Compile"

Tags: c#

So here are some explainations of these two build actions:

> Compile - The file is compiled into the build output. This setting is
>   used for code files.
>
> Content - The file is not compiled, but is included in the Content
>   output group. For example, this setting is the default value for an
>   .htm or other kind of Web file.

Why would .cs files default Build Action be "Content"?  It seems like "Compile" would be more appropriate.

edit:  I created a test .cs file (Class) in the App_Code folder for my test and I am using Visual Studio 2015 (fully updated). This is using the default Web Application template (MVC) in Visual Studio.

edit2: I just did another test and the same thing happened.  Maybe the cause is the project type I am using (ASP.NET MVC Web Application).  It seems like the App_Code folder is the recommended place to put cs files, however, since nothing from this folder can be served to the client.  I haven't made any changes to VS2015's configuration or anything like that.

Comment: Mine default to compile...

Comment: Odd- mind defaulted to "Content".  I created it in the App_Code folder, if that matters.

Comment: What is the App_Code folder..? Maybe it is because you didn't create the file through Visual Studio via Add > New Item?

Comment: The App_Code folder is part of the Web Applications (MVC) project template in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default build action for *.cs files should be **Compile**. You would have to explicitly set it to something else. Some context might be helpful.

Comment: Interesting.  Also, I just added some more information to this post as an edit.  Thanks.